# Is the sentence correct in conveying the meaning

Tags: articles

> *What the scenery!*

Is the above sentence correct and in the usage?

As what a beautiful rose!

Can we write what scenery!

Comment: You don't say what meaning you are trying to convey! (It isn't correct anyway, but you need to say more than just 'is this correct?').

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"What scenery!" is correct. It's an interjection, not a complete sentence, but there is no error.

"What the scenery!" Is a grammar error.  You should not place the word "the" in this position.

Comment: This is a proofreading question. :)